# @ViewChild and @ViewChildren Always Return Undefined, Even when no *ngIf is used

Tags: angular, angular5, viewchild

I am having trouble referencing a child component in a larger project so I dropped these into the project just for my own sanity check.

In any instance @ViewChild AND @ViewChildren ALWAYS return undefined. What I need is to get the position and dimensions of a child element...

What can I do to try and resolve this?

**Components are exported through a module...**

**Used in view like this**

```
<app-parent>
    <app-child></app-child>
</app-parent>
```

**Child:**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-child',
  template: `<div>Stuff</div>`,
  })
export class ChildComponent {
  constructor() { }
}
```

**Parent:**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-parent',
  template: `<div><ng-content></ng-content></div>`,
})
export class ParentComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {

  @ViewChild(ChildComponent) child: any;
  @ViewChildren('app-child') childrenMethod: QueryList<ElementRef>;

  constructor() { }
  ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log(this.child); // returns undefined
  }
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.log(this.child);  // returns undefined
    this.childrenMethod.changes.subscribe(item => {
      console.log('??' + this.childrenMethod); // nothing happens
  });
}
```

Is there a different approach to getting the child element so I can work with it's position and dimensions?

Comment: When using `ng-content` you need to use `ContentChild` instead of `ViewChild`

Comment: What J. Pichardo says: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4vzmax

Comment: I just wanna cry now,, lol. Thank you! One issue though. If I declare @ContentChild(ChildComponent) child: ElementRef; .. this this.child.nativeElement.offsetHeight ... throws an error unhandled error TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetHeight' of undefined